# SQL - Many-Many To Bit "Virtual" Columns?

Tags: sql, select, join, projection

I have the classic Users, UserRoles, and Roles tables. (Any many-many relationship will probably apply, too.)

User and Role have Id as their PK column. Roles has UserId and RoleId as foreign keys.

How would I construct such a SELECT query where I have a bit column for each Role, and each value of the bit columns is whether the user has the role? I have an idea how to do this in LINQ, but I need it in plain SQL.

So, SELECT IsAdmin (What do I put here if I that's what I need to do?), IsModerator (here, too?), ... FROM Users
    JOIN WHAT?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I asume you mean several bit columns, and not a flag column.
I'd advise against using bit, because you need to add them together with either sum or max.
So you should use integer in order to not have to convert/cast.

T_Groups:

```
GRP_ID
GRP_Name 
GRP_IsAdmin AS integer
GRP_IsModerator AS integer
GRP_IsGuest AS integer
```

T_Users

```
USR_ID
USR_DisplayName
USR_UserName
USR_PasswordHash
USR_PassWordSalt
USR_PassWordAlgorithm
```

T_MAP_Users_Groups

```
MAP_USRGRP_ID
MAP_USRGRP_USR_ID
MAP_USRGRP_GRP_ID
```

Query like this:

```
SELECT 
     USR_ID, USR_Name
    ,MAX(GRP_IsAdmin) AS IsAdmin
    ,MAX(GRP_IsModerator) AS IsModerator
    ,MAX(GRP_IsGuest) AS IsGuest

FROM T_Users 
    LEFT JOIN T_MAP_Users_Groups 
        ON MAP_USRGRP_USR_ID = USR_ID

    LEFT JOIN T_Groups
         ON GRP_ID = MAP_USRGRP_GRP_ID

GROUP BY USR_ID, USR_Name
```

Comment: I see how this will work because IsAdmin, IsModerator, and IsGuest are actual columns in Group, so we could join tables to get those values in the result set.